# Generate a Bitcoin taproot address with specific prefix for burning assets

Tags: blockchain, address, taproot, javascript

I would like to generate a bitcoin taproot address (bc1p) for burning assets. Which means not one would have the private key. But in the mean time I would also want a vanity address (an address start with a certain prefix).

I did some search but can't find a tool that meets the above 2 requirements. So I wrote one by my own but it looks very inefficient. Is there any better way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Here's my script:

```
const { validate, getAddressInfo } = require('bitcoin-address-validation');

var chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

prefix = 'bc1pXXXXXX' //THE_PREFIX_I_WANT
subLen = 62 - prefix.length
subDigits = Array(subLen).fill(0)
digit = 0
limit = 36
while (true) {
    subString = ''
    for (i in subDigits) {
        subString = chars[subDigits[i]] + subString
    }
    while (true) {
        subDigits[digit] += 1
        if (subDigits[digit] >= limit) {
            subDigits[digit] = 0
            digit++
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    digit = 0
    addr = prefix + subString
    if (validate(addr)) {
        console.log(addr, 'IS VALID!!')
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use an OP_RETURN output?

Comment: It's not only about burning bitcoins. I'm considering send inscriptions to an inaccessable address, so it can be seen by anyone but no one can touch it.

Comment: An OP_RETURN script could be used just the same. It could potentially also be slightly cheaper than a taproot address.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that